# Android: how to check if partition has file size limit?

Tags: android, file, filesystems

how do I check if a partition has file size limit; ex. on FAT32, there is a 4Gb file size limit

Comment: is this android question or Windows?

Comment: You don't have to check. They all have.

Comment: there is no such limit on NTFS partition. So I want to check if a path is on NTFS or FAT32

Comment: You then better check which partition type it is.

Comment: and how can this be done? I can't find java/android code to achieve this

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a function in java/android to get the file size limit? Do I have to check the actual filesystem and deduct the filez size limit according to the filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how. Use "mount" command, read each line; there is information on the file system used for each mount point.